# How to store User defined data type through DataContext?

Tags: c#, database, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I used DataContractSerializer to save user data but now 
I want to use DataContext for my database design.
But the system existed struture as below cannot be stored through DataContext.

```
class Data
{
   public DataType1;
   public DataType2;
}
```

It seems these APIs cannot support storing user defined data type.
I don't want to separate all data members because this system uses these structure every where.  If I changed the structure, it is hard to maintain and the DataType1 contains a List<> member.  I don't know how to do even though separating 
this structure.

Could you please kindly to give me some suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems these APIs cannot support storing user defined data type

If that were true the api would be completely without purpose.

The `DataContractSerializer` has what appear to be conflicting rules in an attempt to make serialisation more implicit.  You can for example serialise a public type that has public properties and a public default constructor without having to decorate it with a `DataContract` attribute or any of its members with a `DataMember` attribute.

Looks to me that at the very least you need make `Data` a public class.  Most likely you would need to review your other classes to ensure that either they are implicitly serializable or that you explictly mark them up with the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Dear all:
But now I used **[DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx)**

DataContext cannot serialize the user defined type even marked [Serializable].

The workaround seems to separate all the members into one class now.....

Thanks.

Comment: Silverlight does not support the typical .NET serialisation associtated witht the [Serializable] attribute.  Nor does it support the Linq-To-SQL DataContext stuff.  The XML generatated needs to be compatible with `DataContractSerialisation`, see my answer.